# Spring HibernateTemplate: how it deals with transactions?

Tags: java, nhibernate, spring

Could you explain, what happens behind the scene?

Transaction management when using this template in Spring is absolutely unclear.

What if I invoke 10 DAO methods that all use the same Hibernatetemplate
and I invoke them one after another? Every method runs within its own transaction?

It's not effective is not it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you would put your transactions on your service layer see the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you are just using the hibernate template then the out of the box behaviour is to autocommit everything your daos do. You need a transaction manager to look after your this behaviour. Transactions are sort of orthogonal to the hibernate template.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [Spring declarative transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html) on services, not DAOs.

Services know about units of work, not DAOs.

Answer (score 0):

The transactions are defined in services, you want to avoid defining transactions in DAO's
DAO layer with perform the data operations within the transactions defined at the service layer.